# Make telethon raise exception on MTProto errors

Tags: python, telethon

I have a basic client logic, which listens on new messages, but sometimes Telegram API sends me 429 error, which is Too Many Requests, and after this Telethon client just fails to do anything else, because it tries to read the answer from the server, reads 429, tries to do something else, gets 429, so it is an endless loop. The problem is there is no method to understand what is happening. As we can see in the method which does process messages
([telethon/network/mtprotosender.py:493](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/blob/master/telethon/_network/mtprotosender.py#L478))

```
    async def _recv_loop(self):
        ... # skip
            try:
                message = self._state.decrypt_message_data(body)
            except TypeNotFoundError as e:
                # Received object which we don't know how to deserialize
                self._log.info('Type %08x not found, remaining data %r',
                               e.invalid_constructor_id, e.remaining)
                continue
            except SecurityError as e:
                # A step while decoding had the incorrect data. This message
                # should not be considered safe and it should be ignored.
                self._log.warning('Security error while unpacking a '
                                  'received message: %s', e)
                continue
            except BufferError as e:
                if isinstance(e, InvalidBufferError) and e.code == 404:
                    self._log.info('Broken authorization key; resetting')
                    self.auth_key.key = None
                    if self._auth_key_callback:
                        self._auth_key_callback(None)

                    await self._disconnect(error=e)
                else:
                    self._log.warning('Invalid buffer %s', e) # <---------- HERE
                    self._start_reconnect(e)
                return
         ...  # skip
```

it just logs the problem, tries to reconnect (which causes another 429 I guess) and does nothing else, but I need this exception to be raised next so I can understand that the client sends me 429 so I need to sleep for some time or do something. In my logs I see multiple `Invalid buffer Invalid response buffer (HTTP code 429)`, and so client hangs.
How can I determine the error inside my code?

Comment: did you end up solving this?

Comment: @raharley, I guess I did. My solution was to patch (by saying patch I mean substitute needed functions in the class) all the functions, which silently fail. The patch was something like `if 429, then raise YourException()`

Comment: thanks, that's helpful - but what a hack. surprised this isn't handled out the box.